# Async-feature in grails 2.0.0.M1

Tags: grails, asynchronous

i am trying out the async-feature in grails. According to http://grails.org/doc/2.0.0.M1/guide/introduction.html#webFeatures it is now possible to use the servlet 3.0 async-feature in grails. So i tried the following code (copied from the doc):

```
def index() {
    def ctx = startAsync()
    ctx.start {
        render "hello"
        ctx.complete()
    }
}
```

just to see if it works, sadly it does not work :/. 
A groovy.lang.MissingMethodException is thrown. Message: No signature of method: grailsasync.ProductController.startAsync() is applicable for argument types: () values: []. While compiling i get no errors, only while executing.

So i ask myself what did i do wrong? Maybe someone has tried out the new Milestone of grails and can help me with that.

gz Aleks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine. Assuming you've already confirmed that you're running this on a container that supports v 3.0 of the Servlet specification, I'd create an issue about this in the [Grails JIRA](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS)

Comment: Yep i tested it on tomcat 7.0.14. A normal asynchronous servlet works fine on it. I think i follow your advice and create an issue in jira.

Comment: I have read something in jira.grails. There they say i need to change the servlet version in BuildConfig.groovy to "3.0": http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7848 (look comments) . They also say that you might run into another problem: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7756. And that is exactly what happened to me. So for now my conclusion is: many problems with the async-feature, and currently not possible to get it working.

Comment: I think you need to expect to run into a few bugs when using the milestones. If this has already been reported, I'd be surprised if it wasn't fixed in 2.0.0 final.